# How to put initialized structs in a struct?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, vector, initialization

I have a struct :

```
typedef struct 
{      
    int nNum;     
    string str;    
}KeyPair;
```

Then I initialize my struct into something like this:

```
KeyPair keys[] =  
{    
    {0, "tester"},        
    {2, "yadah"},        
    {0, "tester"}  
};
```

And yet, let's say a number of other initializations:

```
KeyPair keysA[] =  
{    
    {0, "tester"},        
    {2, "yadah"},        
    {0, "tester"}  
};   



KeyPair keysB[] =  
{    
    {0, "testeras"},        
    {2, "yadahsdf"},        
    {3, "testerasss"}  
};   



KeyPair OtherkeysA[] =  
{    
    {1, "tester"},        
    {2, "yadah"},        
    {3, "tester"}  
};
```

and like 20 more of 'em.

Now, how do I create another struct and initialize it such that it contains these initiazed KeyPairs?

The reason for this is because I will repetitively call a function whose  parameters would come for these structs. And I DO NOT want to do it this way:

```
pressKeyPairs( keys, sizeof( keys) / sizeof( keys[0] ) );
pressKeyPairs( keysA, sizeof( keysA) / sizeof( keysA[0] ) );
pressKeyPairs( keysB, sizeof( keysB) / sizeof( keysB[0] ) );
pressKeyPairs( OtherkeysA, sizeof( OtherkeysA) / sizeof( OtherkeysA[0] ) );
and so on...
```

So I would like to just loop through a struct containing these inilialized instantiations of KeyPairs...

OR I would like to put these initialized instances of KeyPairs into a vector and just loop through the vector... How do I do that?

Comment: What do you want to do?  You are creating a bunch of arrays of `KeyPair`s; do you want to concatenate them?

Comment: Are you trying to store them all in an array?

Comment: If the other struct contains *pointers* to `KeyPair` arrays, just use the names of the above arrays you declared as the initializers for the pointers. If the other struct actually *contains* `KeyPair` arrays, then you just use another level of nested braces in the initializer.

Comment: Can you consider a vector of map or multi-map?

Comment: Why not `#define PRESS_KEY_PAIRS(keys) pressKeyPairs(keys, sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]))`? Makes your job a lot less error prone, if nothing else. If you're really allergic to macros you could make `pressKeyPairs` a template function that takes a reference to an array and not need to pass the size: `template <size_t N> void pressKeyPairs(KeyPair (&keys)[N])` If you can't change the function, you can write a wrapper to the same effect: `template <size_t N> void myPressKeyPairs(KeyPair (&keys)[N]) { pressKeyPairs(keys, N); }` Short story: You can make your job easier in other ways.

Comment: How do I put these initialized instances of KeyPairs in a vector?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a fixed number key pairs, you could use a structure member function:

```
typedef struct KeyPairs {
    KeyPair keysA[3];
    KeyPair keysB[3];
    KeyPair otherKeysA[3];

    void init() {
       keysA[0].nNum = 0;
       keysA[0].str = "tester";
       keysA[1].nNum = 2;
       keysA[1].str = "yadah";
       keysA[2].nNum = 0;
       keysA[2].str = "tester";

       // and so on for other keys
    }
} KeyPairs;
```

Then use it like so:

```
KeyPairs pairs;
pairs.init();
```

Comment: Your other option (which is probably better) is to have a separate init() function outside of the struct (e.g. in the same class as where you use the structs) that manually iterates through and initializes the structs.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing real C++ and using constructors ?

(note that typedefs are implicits for structs in C++)

```
struct KeyPair
{
    int nNum;     
    string str;

    public:
    KeyPair() {}
    KeyPair(int n, string s) : nNum(n), str(s) {}

};
```

And then use another struct :

```
struct TripleKeyPair
{
    KeyPair keys[3];

    TripleKeyPair() 
    {
        // Your initialisation code goes here
    }
};
```

And finally, I wouldn't advice using names such as :

> KeysA, KeysB, KeysC ...

Arrays are exactly for this. Why note use [std::vector](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/vector/start) ?

Comment: How do I put these initialized instances of KeyPairs in a vector?

Comment: If Google always worked for specific questions like these, StackOverflow wouldn't have had existed... :)

Answer (score 1):

How about using "null" objects as delimiters in the array? You would have to use constructors though:

```
struct KeyPair
{
    KeyPair() : fIsEmpty(true) {}
    KeyPair(int nNum_, const char *szStr) : nNum(nNum_), str(szStr), fIsEmpty(false) {}

    int nNum;
    string str;
    bool fIsEmpty;
};
```

Then you can initialize it like this:

```
KeyPair allKeys[] = 
{
    KeyPair(0, "testeras"),      
    KeyPair(2, "yadahsdf"),
    KeyPair(3, "testerasss"),
    KeyPair(),
    KeyPair(0, "tester"),
    KeyPair(2, "yadah"),
    KeyPair(3, "tester"),
    KeyPair(1, "moreyadah"),
    KeyPair()
};
```

And the iteration is trivial if you implement a kind of strlen() analog for KeyPair object array.

Comment: This is a good alternative to using std::vector since it avoids dynamic memory allocation and provides better initialization semantics without any significant impact on usage semantics.